# How can I force ListBoxItems to display inline in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

```
<ListBox Background="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item0</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item4</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item5</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item6</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

This code above produces this Image below.
[image]

But I want to create something like this image below. Where the box breaks down to the next line at the end of it's parent control. And I want to achieve this using XAML (and C# if required)
[image]

Comment: Try a WrapPanel instead of a StackPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick sample replacing your `StackPanel` with a `WrapPanel`. It binds the width of the `WrapPanel` to the main window, so that items wrap correctly even when the window is resized.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Name="main">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Background="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ElementName=main, Path=Width}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item0</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Might have to play with the settings a bit, since the scrollbars tend to overlap the tiles a little.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just change your ItemsPanelTemplate to

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel MaxWidth="800" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `WrapPanel` *and* to disable the horizontal scroll bar of the list box:

```
<ListBox Background="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item0</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item6</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it modifying your ItemPanelTemplate by replacing StackPanel with WrapPanel. You would also need to assign the MaxWidth of WrapPanel to User Control's width and Orientation Horizontal. For example, assuming your User Control is named "TestControl"

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=TestControl,Path=Width}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Your ListBox would look like.

```
<ListBox Background="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=TestControl,Path=Width}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item0</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Background="White" Width="150" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">Item7</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```